Random string occur when handling file (C++)
Trying to solve some programming exercises when I have to handle files using ifstream. As of now, the code simply opens the file, reads a string, then displays the string. The code looks like this:
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::ifstream inpfile("./polynomial.inp");
  std::string str;
  inpfile >> str;
  std::cout << str;
  inpfile.close();
  return 0;
};

However, when I run it, the output looks like this:
∩╗┐2
The polynomial.inp file contains these information:
2 2
1 2 1

Also, I use VSCode and G++ 6.3.0. Can anyone help me?

Those three characters are the UTF-8 byte order mark EF BB BF, rendered in codepage 437 (default for the console on Windows). Most likely, those three bytes are in fact present at the beginning of the file, it's just that your text editor doesn't show them. Inspect the file in the hex viewer.

Thanks for helping! Just downloaded HxD and they do appear in the file! Do you have any suggestions for preventing this ever happen again?

@DavidPham We probably need more information to do so. Figure out why those bytes are showing up and whether they're doing so predictably, then see if you can figure out a solution. If you can't, you can always come back and ask another question! (Or [edit] this one if you think that fits better.)

Whatever text editor you used to prepare this file, configure it to save files without BOM.
